# Problems configuring an SSH tunnel to a Nexentastor appliance for use with headless Crashplan

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, zfs, ssh-tunnel, nexenta

## Problem

I am attempting to configure an SSH tunnel to a NexentaStor appliance from either a Windows or Linux computer so that I can connect a Crashplan Desktop GUI to a headless Crashplan server running on the Nexenta box, according to these instructions on the Crashplan support site: [Connect to a Headless CrashPlan Desktop](http://support.crashplan.com/doku.php/how_to/configure_a_headless_client).

So far, I've failed to get a working SSH tunnel from from either either a Windows client (using Putty) or a Linux client (using command line SSH). I'm fairly sure the problem is at the receiving end with NexentaStor. A blog article - [CrashPlan for Backup on Nexenta](http://blog.barrkel.com/2010/03/crashplan-for-backup-on-nexenta.html) - indicates that it could be made to work only after "after enabling TCP forwarding in Nexenta in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`" - although I'm not sure how to go about that or specifically what I need to do.

## Things I have tried

Ensuring the Crashplan server on the Nexenta box is listening on port 4243

```
$ netstat -na | grep LISTEN | grep 42
127.0.0.1.4243             *.*                0      0 131072      0 LISTEN
      *.4242               *.*                0      0 65928      0 LISTEN
```

Establishing a tunnel from a Linux host:

```
$ ssh -L 4200:localhost:4243 admin:10.0.0.56
```

and then, from another terminal on the Linux host, using telnet to verify the tunnel:

```
$ telnet localhost 4200
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is #^]'.
```

with nothing more, although the Crashplan server should respond with *something*.

From Windows, using PuTTY I have followed the instructions on the Crashplan support site to establish an equivalent tunnel, but then `telnet` on Windows gives me no response at all and the Crashplan GUI can't connect either. The PuTTY log for the tunnelled connection shows reasonable output:

```
...
2011-11-18 21:09:57 Opened channel for session
2011-11-18 21:09:57 Local port 4200 forwarding to localhost:4243
2011-11-18 21:09:57 Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)
2011-11-18 21:09:57 Started a shell/command
2011-11-18 21:10:09 Opening forwarded connection to localhost:4243
```

but the `telnet localhost 4200` command from Windows does nothing at all - it just waits with a blank terminal.

On the NexentaStor server I've examined the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and everything seems 'normal' - and I've commented out the ListenAddress entries to ensure that I'm listening on all interfaces.

How can I establish a tunnel, and how can I verify that it is working?

Comment: Is the `AllowTcpForwarding` mentioned in the current sshd_config at all?

Comment: @Zoredache `AllowTcpForwarding` is not mentioned in the `sshd_config` although apparently it defaults to `yes`.  Adding an explicit entry for it doesn't improve the situation.

Answer (score 2):

Rob, please try running the ssh tunnel as the `root` user on the NexentaStor server instead of `admin`, and report back.

```
$ ssh -L 4200:localhost:4243 root@10.0.0.56
```

Comment: Connecting as root makes no different to the success of the tunnel, from either Linux or Windows clients.

Comment: BTW - Are you restarting the sshd service between config file changes? Hit enter a couple of times after you connect to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Yes, I'm issuing `svcadm restart ssh` between changes.

Comment: Last suggestions: What version of NexentaStor are you on? Have you updated? When I run ssh tunnels, I tend to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`, just in case. Run an `apt-get install nexenta-lsof` and run an `lsof -i` to check the Crashplan process/port. Lastly, you can post this on the NexentaStor forums: http://nexentastor.org/projects/site/boards if there's any chance there's a firewall issue or rules governing those ports at the `nmc` level.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing you might want to try is verifying that your linux ssh host allows tunneling. I'm using [OpenMediaVault](http://www.openmediavault.org/), and it had a specific setting called "permit to do SSH tunneling" that was unchecked. Checking it allowed me to successfully use the PuTTY method.

Comment: You saved my life (OMV user)

Answer (score 1):

You need to forward to port 4242, not port 4243.

```
ssh -L 4200:localhost:4242 admin:10.0.0.56
```